# How to define algorithm of the view

Tags: mysql

View describes in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/views-table.html). But in this table there are not column for algorithm of view.

How can get algorithm of the view using SQL query? In what table is stored?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the definition or text of the view?

Comment: [algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html) definition. How to define kind - MERGE, TEMPTABLE or UNDEFINED?

Comment: ah. *Another* non-standard MySQL extension...

Answer (score 0):

Views are not stored (except materialized views which MySQL does not support).

Getting the algorithm of a view is as simple as using `SHOW CREATE VIEW view_name;`

Comment: I don't need get view like schema object - only its definition. For example, Navicat can show this property, and I want to know how to get it.

Comment: You can parse a view definition from the SHOW CREATE VIEW. Sometimes it only one way to get correct information;-)

Answer (score 0):

The VIEW_DEFINITION column gives the definition (the SELECT inside the view)

The CHECK_OPTION lets you know if this option was given